# Google Sheets onEdit Calculate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to figure out how I could make an `onEdit` event for the following method.

Example:
Column1 = Value I will enter to calculate Column2 (+/-)
Column2 = Value based on Cell Value (+/-) Column2 based on cell value entered

I need for each row `a1:b1`, `a2:b2` and so on this:

When I enter for example into `A1(-100)` and `B1` have already a value of `200` it should give me the result `100` and delete the value in A1 entered.
Same for `A2(+100)` and `B1(50)` should give me a result of `150` and delete value in `A2`.

So the final result should be `B1 = 100` and `B2 = 150` and so on

I tried it with this Code

```
function onEdit(e){
  var Column1 = 1;
  var Column2 = 2;

  if( e.range.getColumn() == Column1 && e.value){
    e.range.setValue(e.value * e.range.offset(0, Column2 - Column1).getValue());
    }
}
```

But this is just halfway what I need and I got stuck here now for hours. If anyone could help me to finish this would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

According to your explanation, you want to **add** the numbers.

*For example:*

`(-100)` **+** `200` would give you `100`.

Your current scripts lacks these two functionalities:

- It does not add the values.
- It does not clear the value in column `A` after the operation is finished.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const inputCol = 1;
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // get active sheet
  const ar = e.range;
  const row = ar.getRow(); // get edited row
  const col = ar.getColumn(); // get edited column
  if (as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == inputCol){
      const rng = as.getRange(row,inputCol+1);
      rng.setValue(parseInt(e.value)+rng.getValue());  
      ar.clearContent();
  }
}
```

I assume that you want to apply this operation on a particular sheet and hence I added a condition to run the code only for `Sheet1`. If you don't want this behaviour, then remove it altogether. If you want to use a different sheet name then change `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation where my problem was and thanks for the code!